# print enum as String typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

My enum:

```
enum VerificationStatus {
    pending, 
    rejected, 
    verified
}
```

I am trying to print the enum in the following format:

```
console.log(myEnumtoString(VerificationStatus.pending))
```

should print the string

```
"VerificationStatus.pending"
```

I tried:

```
console.log(`${typeof VerificationStatus}.${VerificationStatus[VerificationStatus.pending]}`)
```

But I get this:

```
"object.pending"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work, but it's a bit clumsy:

```
console.log(`${Object.keys({VerificationStatus})[0]}.${VerificationStatus[VerificationStatus.pending]}`)
```

TypeScript compiles enums into variables with values as properties and a map of value names and indexes.

It means the code above uses this *internal* knowledge to print the name of the variable the enum is compiled into. It's brittle and I wouldn't recommend to use it.

As far as TypeScript has no official way how to get the enum name, I would just print it explicitly:

```
console.log(`VerificationStatus.${VerificationStatus[VerificationStatus.pending]}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

define your enum like this

```
enum VerificationStatus {
    pending='pending', 
    rejected='rejected', 
    verified='verified'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you would need a *transformer* like [`ts-nameof`](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof).

Usage:

```
nameof.full(VerificationStatus.pending); // "VerificationStatus.pending"
```